# Estou recebendo o seguinte erro no meu mapeamento JPA: Same column is added more than once with different values for isInsertable

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jpa, annotation

Minhas Classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "pr_localident")
public class Locale implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @EmbeddedId
    private LocaleId localeId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("company")
    @JoinColumn(name="codigo_emp", referencedColumnName = "codigo_emp")
    private Company company;
    
    @ManyToOne()
    @MapsId("branch")
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name="codigo_emp", referencedColumnName = "codigo_emp", insertable=false, updatable=false),
        @JoinColumn(name="codigo_fil", referencedColumnName = "codigo_fil", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    })
    private Branch branch;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("localeName")
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name="codigo_emp", referencedColumnName = "codigo_emp", insertable=false, updatable=false),
        @JoinColumn(name="codigo_local", referencedColumnName = "codigo_local")
    })
    private LocaleName localeName;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("general")
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name="codigo_emp", referencedColumnName = "codigo_emp", insertable=true, updatable=true),
        @JoinColumn(name="codigo_g", referencedColumnName = "codigo_g")
    })
    private General general;
    
    
    //Esse campo de data precisa obrigatoriamente ser null
    @Column(name="data_final")
    private Date dataFinal;
    @Column(name="user_apenas_pedido_compras")
    private String requisicaoSN;

    
//getters and setters


@Embeddable
public class LocaleId implements Serializable {
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @Column(name="codigo_emp")
    private String company;
    @Column(name="codigo_fil")
    private String branch;
    @Column(name="codigo_local")
    private String localeName;
    @Column(name="codigo_g")
    private String general;
    
//getters and setters

@Entity
@Table(name = "gg_local")
public class LocaleName implements Serializable{

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        
        @EmbeddedId
        private LocaleNameId localeNameId;
        
        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @MapsId("company")
        @JoinColumn(name="codigo_emp", referencedColumnName = "codigo_emp")
        private Company company;
        
        @Column(name="nome_local")
        private String nomeLocal;
        @Column(name="ativo_inativo")
        private String ativoInativo;
    //getters and setters

@Embeddable
public class LocaleNameId implements Serializable{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @Column(name="codigo_emp")
    private String company;
    @Column(name="codigo_local")
    private String codigoLocal;
    
    public LocaleNameId() {
        
    }

    public LocaleNameId(String company, String codigoLocal) {
        super();
        this.company = company;
        this.codigoLocal = codigoLocal;
    }
//getters and setters

@Entity
@Table(name = "gg_usuario")
public class User implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @EmbeddedId
    private UserId userId;
    
    
    @MapsId("system")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="codigo_sis", referencedColumnName = "codigo_sis")
    private System system;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="codigo_emp", referencedColumnName = "codigo_emp")
    private Company company;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name="codigo_emp", referencedColumnName = "codigo_emp", insertable=false, updatable=false),
        @JoinColumn(name="codigo_fil", referencedColumnName = "codigo_fil", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    })
    private Branch branch;
    
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name="codigo_emp", referencedColumnName = "codigo_emp", insertable=false, updatable=false),
        @JoinColumn(name="codigo_g", referencedColumnName = "codigo_g", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    })
    private General pessoa;
    @Column(name="user_name")
    private String userName;
    @Column(name="status_user")
    private String statusUser;
    @Column(name="codigo_grp_user")//chave estrangeira
    private String codigoGrpUser;
    @Column(name ="senha")
    private String senha;
    
//getters and setters
@Embeddable
public class UserId implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @Column(name="codigo_sis")
    private String system;
    @Column(name="codigo_user")
    private String codigoUser;

    public UserId() {
        
    }
//getters and setters

@Entity
@Table(name="gg_filial")
public class Branch implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @EmbeddedId
    private BranchId branchId;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("company")
    @JoinColumn(name="codigo_emp", referencedColumnName = "codigo_emp")
    private Company company;
    
    @Column(name="nome_fil")
    private String nomeFil;
    @Column(name="cgc_g")
    private String cnpj;
    
//getters and setters

@Embeddable
public class BranchId implements Serializable {
    
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    
    @Column(name="codigo_emp")
    private String company;
    @Column(name="codigo_fil")
    private String branch;
//getters and setters

@Entity
@Table(name="gg_empresa")
public class Company implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @Id
    @Column(name="codigo_emp")
    private String codigoEmp;
    @Column(name="nome_emp")
    private String nomeEmp;
    @Column(name="cgc_g")
    private String cnpj;
    @Column(name="cam_logo")
    private String pathLogo;
    @Column(name="codigo_munic")
    private String codigoMunicipio;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "company")
    private List<Branch> branchs;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "company")
    private List<General> general;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "company")
    private List<Locale> locales;
    //getters and setters

@Entity
@Table(name = "gg_geral")

public class General implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private GeneralId generalId;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("company")
    @JoinColumn(name="codigo_emp", referencedColumnName = "codigo_emp")
    private Company company;
    
    @Column(name="nome_g")
    private String nameG;
    @Column(name="email_g")
    private String emailG;
    @Column(name="cpf_g")
    private String cpfG;
    @Column(name="ativo_inativo")
    private String ativoInativo;

//getters and setters


@Embeddable
public class GeneralId implements Serializable{
    
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @Column(name="codigo_emp")
    private String company;
    @Column(name="codigo_g")
    private String codigoG;
    
//getters and setters
```

Já tentei a abordagem das chaves primárias compostas com @IdClass, mas o erro foi o mesmo.
Creio que o problema pode estar relacionado as classes que possuem chave estrangeira como primária.
Exemplo Locale.class que possui 4 chaves primárias e todas elas são estrangeiras.
Abaixo segue print das chaves estrangeiras no postgres. (Obs: Não desejo fazer alterações com relação ao banco, pois estou integrando minha aplicação a um banco já existente do cliente):[print das chaves estrangeiras no postgres](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1z9Vx.png)

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: Encontrei o problema. Erro meu de entendimento. Minha classe Locale possuia o atributo company com a anotação @MapsId indicando que aquele atributo estava como chave no LocaleID. O problema é que esse atributo company, não vem da classe LocaleId e sim da classe Company. Fiz a correção pra esse atributo e para outros que também se encaixavam e o erro não surgiu mais. Em resumo eu estava tentanto referenciar uma chave estrangeira com outra chave estrangeira.